# Logstash - Offline Plugin Installation

Tags: ruby, plugins, logstash

I have tried searching on various internet forums about the offline installation of Logstash plugins, but haven't found the solution that we can implement.

**What I want to achieve is:**
Install the following two logstash plugins:

```
logstash-filter-mutate-master
logstash-filter-aggregate-master
```

**My Limitations Are:**
At my company, there is strictly no Internet connectivity on Linux servers. Therefore, I need a solution where I could download some off-the-shelf package on my Windows machine, and then unpack it on the Linux machine, which would install the plugins I require.

I have looked at the [Logstash documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/offline-plugins.html#CO9-1), which advises on how to install plugins offline, but that also needs a 'Staging' server which has logstash source-code and has Internet connectivity - the latter is non-existent in my organisation.

I would greatly appreciate if you could advise how to approach this. At present, when I try to install the 'mutate' plugin, here's the error I see:

```
$ bin/logstash-plugin install --local --no-verify
Installing...

Plugin not found, aborting

ERROR: Installation Aborted, message: Could not find gem 'ci_reporter_rspec (>= 0) java' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or installed on this machine.
```

Thank you.

Comment: You'll also need to have all dependencies locally installed as well so you can run `gem dependency logstash-plugin` to see what it requires

Comment: I don't see the `-master` on Github so maybe try running those both without `-master`

Comment: I removed the '-master' suffix from the directory names and plugin-names in my Gemfile and I still see the same error relating to: "Could not find gem 'ci_reporter_rspec "

Comment: Did you run `gem dependency logstash-filter-mutate` and `logstash-filter-aggregate ` to get a list of all dependencies those require?  You'll need to have those all installed on the same local machine as well.

Comment: I found an alternative to the `logstash-filter-mutate` and `logstash-filter-aggregate` for the purpose of our ELK instance. I am now using the `ruby` plugin, which was already installed for Logstash - and I have written ruby code to create new fields I wanted.

Comment: If my answer is usefull, feel free to upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a logstash plugin in offline.
First way ;
You must change gemfile in logstash directory. As an example, download plugin source in somewhere of your logstash directory then modify gemfile in logstash directory with plugin name and path.

```
gem "logstash-input-example-plugin", :path => "./plugins/logstash-input-example-plugin"
```

After that just run the below command

```
bin/logstash-plugin install --no-verify
```

You can follow this link :

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/logstash/logstash_plugins.htm

Second way; using with gem file of the plugin. As an example;

```
bin/logstash-plugin install /path/to/logstash-output-kafka-1.0.0.gem
```

You can follow this link :

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/working-with-plugins.html